# make function to saved email with id user in action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want saved email by user id, but I don't know how to do this example if user have email : test@gmail.com and add an event the database should save her email how do this if you know tell me please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

i try to make a function but no success help me plzz

enter image description here

Comment: `User.Identity.Name` will get you the current username of the logged-in user.

Comment: P.S. in future please don't add images of code, they are unhelpful to the people trying to answer on here. Code is text, so please paste it as text.